# Disable AzureFileCopy@2 pre job?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am using Azure Devops Pipelines (YAML).

I have a AzureFileCopy@2 task which copies file from the source into a Storage Account. The Storage Account is created dynamically by an earlier ARM deploy task (the ARM task outputs the SA name which is then parsed into a variable for later consumption).

The AzureFileCopy@2 task works perfectly and copies all the files into the Storage Account. But, I notice in the run that the AzureFileCopy@2 task actually runs twice - once by me and once as a "pre-job". The pre-job of course fails with a warning that it can't reference the Storage Account (because by that stage I haven't created the variable).

Fortunately, it's only a warning but it is rather annoying to have that warning in every run.
I believe that pre-jobs can't be disabled (though I could drop that is a a feature enhancement) so is there a better way of handing this presumably common scenario?

Thanks in advance

EDIT: Obfuscated YAML added:

```
variables:
  My.Configuration: 'Release'
  My.SQLProject: 'contoso.api'
  My.ARMProject: 'contoso.azure.templates'
  My.IntEnvironment: 'i'
  My.ResourceGroupNumber: 66
  My.ArtifactLocation: 'drop'

# BUILD STAGES ARE HERE  

- stage: 'Stage_Deploy'
  displayName: 'Stage Deploy'

  jobs:
  - deployment: 'Job_Deploy'
    pool:
      vmImage: 'windows-2019'
    displayName: 'Job Deploy'
    environment: 'env1'
    strategy:
     runOnce:
       deploy:
         steps:
         - download: none

          - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
           displayName: 'Download Pipeline Artifacts from Drop'
           inputs:
             buildType: 'current'
             targetPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)'

         - task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
           displayName: 'ARM Deployment'
           inputs:
             deploymentScope: 'Resource Group'
             azureResourceManagerConnection: 'CONTOSO CONNECTION'
             subscriptionId: 'aaaaaaaa-0000-0000-00000-aaaaaaaaaaaaa'
             action: 'Create Or Update Resource Group'
             resourceGroupName: 'contoso-$(My.IntEnvironment)-eun-core-$(My.ResourceGroupNumber)-rg'
             location: 'North Europe'
             templateLocation: 'Linked artifact'
             csmFile: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/$(My.ArtifactLocation)/$(My.ARMProject)/azuredeploy.json'
             csmParametersFile: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/$(My.ArtifactLocation)/$(My.ARMProject)/azuredeploy.parameters.json'
             overrideParameters: '-environment $(My.IntEnvironment)'
             deploymentMode: 'Incremental'
             deploymentOutputs: 'ARMOutput'

         - task: PowerShell@2
           condition: true
           displayName: 'Parse ARM Template Outputs'
           inputs:
             targetType: filePath
             filePath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/$(My.ArtifactLocation)/$(My.ARMProject)/Parse-ARMOutput.ps1'
             arguments: '-ARMOutput ''$(ARMOutput)'''

         - task: AzureFileCopy@2
           condition: true
           displayName: 'Copy Static Web Content to SA'
           inputs:
             SourcePath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/$(My.ArtifactLocation)'
             azureSubscription: 'CONTOSO CONNECTION'
             Destination: AzureBlob
             storage: '$(ARM.AppDataStorageName)'
             ContainerName: static
```

Then, when I run it, the following stages happen:
1. Initialize job
2. Pre-job: Copy Static Web Content to SA

It is this pre-job that, in the debugging shows this:

```
##[debug]StorageAccountRM=$(ARM.AppDataStorageName)
<other debug lines followed by...>
##[warning]Can\'t find loc string for key: StorageAccountDoesNotExist
```

Later on the task "Copy Static Web Content to SA" runs as a normal task and it runs fine.

Comment: Hi Mark, could you share some details about your yaml file after deleting personal info if it exists? And a bit more info about the warning you get could be better for us to check this issue :)

Comment: Hi Lance, thanks for the reply. I've edited the OP with the info. Cheers!

Comment: After my check this is by design of the code of AzureFileCopy task, so the warning is hard to avoid. Will add more details(including source code) about the cause of the warning tomorrow :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Fortunately, it's only a warning but it is rather annoying to have
>   that warning in every run. I believe that pre-jobs can't be disabled
>   (though I could drop that is a a feature enhancement) so is there a
>   better way of handing this presumably common scenario?

Sorry but I'm afraid it's not supported to disable the warning. The warning occurs because it's by design.

(The source code of AzureFileCopyV2 task causes this behavior.)

**More details:**

We can find source of that task [here](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/AzureFileCopyV2). It contains one [task.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/add-build-task?view=azure-devops#taskjson) file in which defines content like this:

```
  "instanceNameFormat": "$(Destination) File Copy",
    "prejobexecution": {
        "Node": {
            "target": "PreJobExecutionAzureFileCopy.js"
        }
    },
```

The `task.json` file describes the build or release task and is what the build/release system uses to render configuration options to the user and to know which scripts to execute at build/release time. Since the `task.json` has definition like `prejobexecution`, the predefined pre-job task will do the check about the inputs defined in [PreJobExecutionAzureFileCopy.js](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/AzureFileCopyV2/PreJobExecutionAzureFileCopy.ts#L22) file. Including the Storage Account.

So this is something by design of the code of AzureFileCopyV2 task, we can't disable the warning in pre-job task. If you do want to resolve that warning, you can consider using [AzureFileCopyV1](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/AzureFileCopyV1) in which doesn't define the `prejobexecution`, but this is **not recommended**. Compared with Version1, Version2 has some improvement and fixes some old issues.

Comment: Hi Lance, yes I did look at the code before posting and saw that. (Though I didn't look at V1, so thanks for that heads up.) Indeed, I had planned to argue that it's more "by code" than "by design" but the fact that it has specifically been implemented between V1 and V2 means it must indeed be "by design". Personally (and I speak only for myself - others may differ in this view), I think this is a retrograde step because there is no facility to make the prejobexecution conditional. Perhaps this is something that could be added to V3?

Comment: @Mark As I know the V3 has preview version, so your opinion may not be added to V3. But if you want to make it conditional, I think you can suggest this feature request in [Developer Community forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html). If it gets enough points, the product team would consider it seriously.

Comment: Yes indeed - I realized that after posting. V4 maybe. :-) As it turns out, I reverted back to V1 and it worked perfectly - no more warnings. Will add a feature request, though given the "edge case" (creating the environment variable dynamically and then consuming it in AzureFileCopy) I can't see it getting much traction. ;-\

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, you can also update your question with your feature request. People who interested in it can vote for you then :)